# which Linux operating system will go for long term usage

Tags: centos, rhel8, rocky-linux, oracle9i

Looking replacement of centos7

centos7 will expire on 30Th June 2024. so I am looking alternative like RHEL9. I dont know why, but rhel usage is low?